# UILabel reveal animation (without moving or resizing the text)

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, uilabel

I have been struggling with this for about a day. Basically I want to reveal a label from bottom to top without the text moving or resizing at any point. A reveal effect. Like in the image below[image]

All the solutions I have came to so far cause the text to move. I even tried doing a scale transform (with setting anchor to bottom) but this caused the text inside to resize when animation is happening. I also tried putting the label in a view and resize that view (and setting autoresize subview to NO and clip subview to YES) but it still causes the label inside it to move.

Answer (score 2):

Place an opaque view on top of the Hello World and slide it upwards. If you have UI elements above it, make sure that they are above the sliding element.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lable. Then create a view and put above it. It will make lable hidden. Then move the view up.

Comment: There will be things under this label so putting on top of everything a moving view isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the reverted direction is acceptable (reveal from top to bottom) you could just animate the frame origin and the frame size. If the size of a label is smaller than the text the lower part will be cut off. Sounds like the easiest solution with a small compromise.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if someone else is looking for an answer to this you could use:

```
-(void)inverseResizeView: (UIView *)view width:(int)deltaWidth height:(int)deltaHeight {
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x - deltaWidth, view.frame.origin.y - deltaHeight, view.frame.size.width + deltaWidth, view.frame.size.height + deltaHeight); 
}
```

Use it like this as an example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8 animations:^{

    [self inverseResizeView: text.container width: 0 height: text.container.height];

}];
```

To make a inversed animation on a view.